# stick page to left bottom corner instead of default left top?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, media-queries

The portfolio I am working on is a nightmare. For some odd reason, media queries are working only for some resolutions. Hopefully, if there is a way to make everything stick to low left bottom instead of browser default left top, it could solve some issues. Including screen of media queries, but I doubt there is any mistake...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, regarding the align to bottom left, try this:

```
body{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0
}
```

Regarding the queries, it seems that they're overlapping (height 700 and height 710)  that might be causing your issues.

Comment: 700 is a max height, 710 is a min height... Are they overlapping ?

Comment: Well it does stick the page to bottom. However it totally screws all content,so it doesn't work for me.